# Testing Android App using greendao with Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, greendao

I am new to android testing and trying to write unit tests (running on local jvm) using mockito in Android Studio.

My IDE setup (gradle scripts) is done so far.

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

   // Unit testing dependencies.
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

In my app I am using `greendao` as ORM but have no abstraction of this layer yet (planned for future).
When I try to test parts of my application code which are using database related classes (like `SqliteOpenHelper`, `SqliteDatabase` for setting up database, `SQLiteStatement` for compiling statements, etc.) the test exits with exception, for example with *SQLiteOpenHelper not mocked* .

Is it at all possible to write unit tests in this scenario mocking the database (without investing now time to abstract the database layer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to get the right `Context` for initializing the database layer.
Using robolectric you can use `RuntimeEnvironment.application` to get a `Context` object in the test environment, so initializing the database layer with unit tests are running on the local JVM without any device or emulator.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by the keyword is "RuntimeEnvironment.application"

Comment: sorry for the confusing answer, i have edited my solution.